# Aligning text horizontally in a ordered list format using css?

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to align the text horizontally in a ordered list using CSS. I want the list words paris prelude to be aligned next to each other horizontally instead of stacking up on each other. I want the words in the list paris prelude to not stack up like this:
1.Paris
Prelude

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>007 Nightfire | Missions</title>
    </head>
    <style type>    
    h1 {
        font-size:45px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    body {
            background-color:#F0F8FF;
    }
    .list {
            border-color:coral;
            margin-left:-50%;
            position:relative;
            bottom:193px;
            display:inline;
    }
    div {
        border:2px double;
        border-color:#2F4F4F;
        padding:180px;
        margin-left:32%;
        margin-right:32%;
        
    }
    </style>
    <h1><u>Missions</h1></u>
    <body>
    <hr>
    <div class="div">
    <ol class="list">
    <ol>
        <li>Paris Prelude</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving  a width of more than 85px

Comment: basically:
<ol class="list">
<ol style="width: 90px;">

Comment: can you add this to your answer? You should be able to use the code formatter or just surround the html with backticks (next to the 1 on US keyboards)

Answer (score 0):

Use `white-space:nowrap;` inside your style for `.list`

Additionally - as well as it is not having a negative impact (at least at the moment) - remove the second opening `<ol>` tag.
Open as much as you close.
[image]